# GeoEye BGRN --> RGB

Tags: gdal

I got many GeoEye files with BGRN color format. The image looks gray.
-co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB ALPHA=NO gives greenish color. Rearranging bands does not work too.

Could someone help me convert this image to "natural color" image using gdal_translate .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have it currently in BGRN and want RGB the obvious solution is:

gdal_translate -b 3 -b 2 -b 1 bgrn.tif rgb.tif

You mention rearranging bands does not work.  Could you clarify what you try and what happens?

Comment: I did exact the same command above. BGRN is B G R Nir. But the result image is kind of greenish. Would it be the RBG is that how it looks, originally?

Comment: @alsaleem, have you solved the greenish problem?